# Where to start with 'Motor for Intake Manifold Flap (V157): Open or Short to Ground'

Tags: engine, audi, warning-light

I recently hooked my 2005 Audi A3 to VCDS after the engine management light came on and got the reading:

> Motor for Intake Manifold Flap (V157): Open or Short to Ground

I have seen various images on forums where people have taken off what appears to be a box containing cogs which have worn away resulting in the same error code. I am looking to locate this myself and check the flap is opening and closing.

My first question is, where can i find the 'flap' and secondly where can i find the motor that controls the 'flap' to check the teeth on the cogs have not worn away? Any help is appreciated. I have attached an image of my engine. Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting around I found the Audi service manual for the A3 2004 and greater. I found it here:

[Audi service workshop manual](http://websunrise.org/manuals/auto/audi/2.pdf)

Page 13 shows a disassembled engine with the motor for the intake manifold clearly labelled. I'm sure similar vehicle makes and models will have these service manuals somewhere and im sure this will help me locate other potentially problematic areas.

Hope this helps someone else!